# How to optimize performance of appending to CLOB in UPDATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that I need to update:

```
create table test_tab(id number, first varchar2(100), second clob);
insert into test_tab values (1, 'john', 'kowalski');
insert into test_tab values (2, 'michael', 'surname');
```

Now, for every record in my table, I want to append a string to the clob field. I could use an usual concatenation operator:

```
update test_tab set second = second || 'some_string,';
```

And this works, but because my actual table is like 80k rows, the update process lasts for too long.

I'm thinking about using DBMS_LOB.APPEND(), but I don't know how to use it in UPDATE and if it's gonna help the performance.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data in the `second` column needs to be updated, for every record, and this work cannot be avoided.  How long is "too long?"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - The update for only one column lasts about 30 seconds. Sometimes I need to call the procedure for more than one column, so this time is multiplied.

Comment: I upvoted you, but I have never heard of a mass record update, certainly not one which would speed things up.

Comment: [You can do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6572015/266304) but you'd need to test to see if it's any faster. [Also see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10331912/266304) which compares performance of substring options; you might see similar variation, and it might depend on your version/platform potentially.

Comment: I suppose the table is properly indexed.Using DBMS_LOB.APPEND() surely is a good approach, but this would need to happen in PL/SQL. Have a look here: http://www.talkapex.com/2009/06/how-to-quickly-append-varchar2-to-clob.html ... seems to account exactly for your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to update EVERY record in the table it is always faster to recreate table as select (CTAS). Regardless which method you are updating LOB column.

Example:

```
create table temp
as
select id, first, second||' some_string' as second
  from test_tab;

rename test_tab to old_test_tab; -- you can drop it later
rename temp to test_tab;

-- then you need to move all indexes, grants and etc from old_test_tab to test_tab;
```

Comment: Hey @Rusty. Thank you for your answer. Could you please precise what do you mean by 'recreate table'? Or maybe provide a little example of it?