# insert table that contains blob column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert table that contains blob column, but I got an error.

Generated Script (There are more lines for a single record):

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

Insert into "REGP"."Profile" (ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,SPEAKER_PIC,SPEAKER_BIO) values (1,'Anthony','Smith',utl_raw.cast_to_raw(HEXTORAW('626567696E2030207575656E636F64652E6275660D0A6C505B5F23462C2E5F505A2020242449263234382020302420202024'))
|| TO_BLOB(HEXTORAW('2020302020505B5F2346502342402958202230382724412C322531283224413836253134362621403525314035254134380D'))
|| TO_BLOB(HEXTORAW('0A6C255140362551403725513C362551403F2A2220382652343B253134412C3224452A324C4E2B42583727532C582C525457'))
```

error

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got BLOB
00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s".
```

Do I miss anything?

and this is my what I tried with the purposed solution:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

Insert into "REGP"."Profile" (ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,SPEAKER_PIC,SPEAKER_BIO) values (1,'Anthony','Smith', utl_raw.cast_to_raw('626567696E2030207575656E636F64652E6275660D0A6C505B5F23462C2E5F505A2020242449263234382020302420202024'), utl_raw.cast_to_raw('2020302020505B5F2346502342402958202230382724412C322531283224413836253134362621403525314035254134380D'), utl_raw.cast_to_raw('0A6C255140362551403725513C362551403F2A2220382652343B253134412C3224452A324C4E2B42583727532C582C525457')
```

and I got an error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
```

Comment: The concatenation operator - `||` - is for joining **strings**. Blobs aren't strings.

Comment: so what should I replace -| |- with? @APC

Comment: Have a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6572015/146325).

Comment: I've tried that solution, but it just come up with another error ``result of string concatenation is too long`` @APC

Comment: You have 5 columns in the table, and you're inserting 4 values, or the SQL you pasted is not complete. And can you add the code with the proposed solution?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, there are more lines for a single record. I've added code with the purposed solution above @gsalem

Comment: You don't seem to have applied the proposed solution. Did you create the function that actually concatenates the lobs? your code does not show that, or at least that you used it.