# Mix both text and images data in one blob

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, blob

I am studying about the BLOB in SQL Server. The data types allowed for BLOB storage in SQL Server are `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)`.
As I know, `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is suitable to store text data whereas images can be stored in `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns.

Based on the theory, is it possible for me to store both text data and images in one BLOB?

Comment: Did you try DBMS_LOB.APPEND?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570868/how-can-i-append-concatenate-blob-data-to-a-blob-column-using-sql-update-command

Comment: I assume you meant `images can be stored in VARBINARY(MAX)`?

Comment: You can store whatever you like in them, but you have to come up with a "schema" for how you encode both text and binary data in the same column. The bigger question is; why would you want to? You're defeating the purpose of a relational database.

Comment: @Hanna - pretty sure that is not SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK I understand that images can be stored in VARBINARY(MAX) and text data can be stored in NVARCHAR(MAX). I would try to mix both images and text data in one BLOB. Is possible to do it?

Comment: I already answered that - yes - but why?

Comment: And **you** have to come up with an encoding method. Its not handled implicitly.

Comment: And your question has a mistake - as I commented.

Comment: @DaleK Do you mean that it is better to separate both image and text data in two columns? Can I use VARBINARY(MAX) for both image and text data in one blob?

Comment: @DaleK ok thanks. I will figure it out more.

Comment: Yes it is much better to do that. You haven't told me why you want to combine them? (And I've told you twice that yes you can).

Comment: @DaleK I'm doing a research to store my data in this type of columns so I am thinking of the possibilities mix both images and text data in one blob. Thanks for your answering.

Comment: Why are you so desperate to use a single column? An empty (null) column takes up no space so why does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

As Dale K said, you would need to define some kind of "schema" for it, but you could store both in `VARCHAR(MAX)` by converting the images to a base64 encoded string, then storing as:

```
Text=<text> 
Image=<base64 string>
```

Then, when reading the data, you can parse for "Text=" or "Image="

Comment: Or vice-versa, you can store both in `VARBINARY(MAX)`.